# LibGdx - Scroll in an inner window

Tags: java, libgdx, stage

I want to scroll in an inner window, I've included the description as an image:

[image]

I want to be able to scroll in the inner window where the text is. I know how to scroll, but the text is also visible when it isn't in the inner window anymore.

How can I scroll in the inner window, that the text in invisible when it's out from the inner window?

Comment: I've tried do set a viewport just as big as the inner window is and then i passed it to a stage..  I've also tried to put a Spritebatch in a Spritebatch, bit this also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Use Scene2D with a [scrollpane](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html).